# deploy a webmapping application

Tags: hibernate, deployment, postgis

As part of my training, I have developed an application webmapping: I used Java JEE and Hibernate with Postgis database, and a cartographic server geoserver (geoserver is deployed, on glassfish which is housed by default with neatbeans). Now I want to give this application to the enterprise. What are the steps to follow to get there knowing that we want to use this application locally without network? (Must I have postgis installed on the other machine?)

Comment: Please translate into English per forum rules

Comment: ok thanks you, as part of my training I have developed an application webmapping: I used java jee and hibernate with postgis  database, and a cartographic server geoserver (geoserver is deployed, on glassfish which is housed by default with neatbeans ), now i want to give this application to the enterprise, what are the steps to follow to get there knowing that we want to use this application locally without network. (must i have  postgis installed on the other machine? )